# optimize time(NULL) call in c++

Tags: c++, optimization

I have a system that spend 66% of its time in a time(NULL) call.

It there a way to cache or optimize this call?

Context: I'm playing with Protothread for c++. Trying to simulate threads with state machines. So Therefore I cant use native threads.

Here's the header:

```
#ifndef __TIMER_H__
#define __TIMER_H__

#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

class Timer
{
private:
    time_t initial;
public:
    Timer();
    unsigned long passed();
};

#endif
```

and the source file:

```
#include "Timer.h"

using namespace std;

Timer::Timer()
{
    initial = time(NULL);
}

unsigned long Timer::passed()
{
    time_t current = time(NULL);
    return (current - initial);
}
```

UPDATE:
Final solution!
The cpu cycles it going away somewhere, and if I spend them being correct. That is
not so bad after all.

```
#define start_timer() timer_start=time(NULL)
#define timeout(x)   ((time(NULL)-timer_start)>=x)
```

Comment: How high precision does your timer need to be?

Comment: The most important is to make it effective. 1 sec is acceptable.

Comment: Yes, please create another question as title hasn't got anything to do with map. Someone using google to search for map-optimization later would miss this.

Comment: On Solaris, use gettimeofday(); that is far quicker than any ordinary system call (such as getpid()), so much so that it must be reading a memory location rather than making a system call with context switch to the kernel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I presume you are calling it within some loop which is otherwise stonkingly efficient.

What you could do is keep a count of how many iterations your loop goes through before the return value of time changes.

Then don't call it again until you've gone through that many iterations again.

You can dynamically adjust this count upwards or downwards if you find you're going adrift, but you should be able to engineer it so that on average, it calls time() once per second.

Here's a rough idea of how you might do it (there's many variations on this theme)

```
int iterations_per_sec=10; //wild guess
int iterations=0;

while(looping)
{
    //do the real work

    //check our timing
    if (++iterations>iterations_per_sec)
    {
        int t=time(NULL);
        if (t==lasttime)
        {
            iterations_per_sec++;
        }
        else
        {
            iterations_per_sec=iterations/(t-lasttime);
            iterations=0;
            lastime=t;

            //do whatever else you want to do on a per-second basis
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like you done it before. Now I have some new Ideas.

Comment: Not too bad and it's auto adjusting, including quickly in the right direction if you're not calling time() often enough [inaccuracy] and slowly in the other direction, calling it too often [inefficiency but still accuracy]. +1 for a clever solution.

Comment: Tried this on my main loop and it improves by 185%!

Comment: OK,could not use it in the mail loop. It was to practical to have a accurate main loop. Then I could measure the effectiveness of the other parts.

Comment: This only work as long as we have constant rate. It the rate changes to half or one of a tenth. Then we will get a new time(NULL) in ten seconds, for a short period.

Answer (score 6):

That sounds quite much, given that `time` only has a precision of 1 second. Sounds like you call it way too often. One possible improvement would be to maybe call it only each 500ms. So it will still hit every second.

So instead of calling it 100 times a second, start off a timer that rings every 500ms, taking the current time and storing it into an integer. Then, read that integer 100 times a second instead.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out, you cannot cache it, as the whole point of time() is to give you the current time, which obviously changes all the time.

The real question however probably is: Why is the program calling time() so frequently? I can't think of any good reason to do so.

Is it polling time()? In that case sleep() might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Call it less often - unless you really need the current time hundreds of times a second, you shouldn't be calling it that often.

EDIT:
After trying it, I'm even more curious, I realize you might be on a small embeded system, but on my system, I had no problems running 10,000,000 calls to time() in a second.  You're likely doing something seriously wrong given that time() is only going to change once a second.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm building state machines. Every statemachne need to look if the timer is done. So  there goes my calls. At the moment I'm benchmarking with 1M state machines.

Comment: Ah, I see - then I'd say add an extra thread or a timer that sets an integer to the current time every 250 ms or so, and just check against that integer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Unix, you may consider using gettimeofday (http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/gettimeofday.html) - it's faster and has better precision.

Answer (score 1):

Caching will not help, unless and until you don't want the current time. Can you post some code?

Comment: I guess if I only make the call half the time. And use the cached value I will save some cycles.

Comment: Well, that is the whole point -- how frequently you need to know the current time. Tinker around.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends, but saving the result won't help if you always want the current time. `time( NULL )` likely results in a system call, which will take time since you have to switch to/from kernel mode.

What you **can** do is read the tsc at the same time that you get the current time, then read the tsc again when you want to get the current time, and add the number of cycles/CPU speed to your time.

There are some answers about `rdtsc` on here that should help you.

Edit: see my answer in [Timer to find elapsed time in a function call in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638269/timer-to-find-elapsed-time-in-a-function-call-in-c) for more information about `rdtsc`.

Also note that I don't particularly recommend this unless you **absolutely have to.** It is highly likely that calling `rdtsc`, subtracting from the previous `rdtsc` converting that to a fractional equivalent in seconds by dividing by your cpu spped will be *slower* than just calling `time()` again.

Answer (score 0):

Typically what you can do is save the result of time off into a local variable, and then use that as your current time until you perform some blocking call, or some long running CPU intensive section of code.

What are you doing that you need to call time this often and can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a thread which called time() a few times a second and then slept, updating a shared variable.

A quick skim of Protothread implied that it didn't use OS threads, so you might get away with no memory barriers. Otherwise something like an efficient read/write lock should mean it's negligible cost.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate thread which would run an endless loop that would sleep() for 1 second (or less if you need finer granularity) and then update the timestamp value.

Other threads would just check this timestamp value without any performance penalty.

Comment: If a thread requests sleeping for 1 second, isn't that a *minimum*? Couldn't the OS decide not to schedule the thread for longer if it desired? Then it seems your time could end up arbitrarily inaccurate.